# Took intake manifold off to replace knock sensor and takes two key turns to start engine on cold star

Tags: starting, chevrolet, fuel-system, silverado

I replaced my knock sensors intake gasket cam shaft sensor and oil pressure sensor and now my 2005 chevy silverado 1500 Takes two key turns to start up, only sometimes, on a cold start. It was not doing this before hand and sometimes on a cold start it is fine. What could be the problem?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Double check your connection to your camshaft sensor is good. Also, double check to see if there are any engine codes.

Comment: Just checked and its all good and theres no codes sorry i forgot to mention that